# Random Shutdown Issue on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, shutdown, toshiba-laptop

I have a Toshiba satellite c650 laptop with i3 processor and 3 Gigs of RAM. Windows 10 Professional is loaded on my laptop.

I face a strange issue of random shutdowns. Happens once or twice a day. Sometimes on lucky days, the issue doesn't appear.

My Laptop battery is dead(doesn't last more than 4 minutes), so it's always plugged in.

What can be the possible issue and how can i determine and fix the cause.

Comment: The problem is likely connected to the batter.  Can the batter be replaced?

Comment: Does Windows gracefully shut down or does the laptop abruptly turn off? Check the Event Log.

Comment: abruptly, no grace

Comment: Please help anyone. Even taking the battery out doesn't make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

I had random shutdowns and it was driving me crazy. Here is how I fixed mine. Ran windows update troubleshooter as administrator and it found some errors and fixed them. I deleted software that I thought would be causing them. Laptop was running fine, no random shutdowns. I then started adding back software and for me it was the Brothers printer software that was corrupting the windows 10 operating system.