# Laptop having boot up and performance issues

Tags: boot, windows-10, bsod, toshiba-laptop

I am having a Toshiba C650 laptop with intel core i3 processor and 3 Gigs of RAM running Windows 10 Pro. Lately, I am experiencing issues which are making the device unbearable.

It all started with [random shutdowns](https://superuser.com/questions/1055449/random-shutdown-issue-on-windows-10), someone at superuser suggested battery change and i did it. This didn't help and one bad day, the laptop just refused to boot up.

I reinstalled Windows 10 using USB and within couple of days, the laptop again refused to boot up with **Blue screen of death** depicting **irql_not_less_or_equal error** and **storahci.sys** error.

Again i had to do the repair using the bootable USB. Now, the laptop is extremely slow to boot up and i fear seeing the blue screen again.

And just now, Skype showed **unable to sign in due to a disk i/o error**.

Are all these issue correlated and do they lead to some conclusive answer as to what might be the issue. Should i sell the laptop as its around 5 year old.

Comment: It sounds like your hard drive is failing.

Comment: @Mokubai is there any way to repair it? Replacing isn't possible as I can't find a new one

Answer (score 0):

As Long as hardware is Okay, Software problems can be solved. There can be different reasons why it is happening with your  system. But for Answer, I suggest, have you tried clean format to your hard disk. If no, then give it a try. And then Try to update Boot driver after fresh installation of OS. If its latest then try to reinstall it. You can easily find answer on web ,how to do that.

As per my understanding, you have issues with your boot settings, If you clean format your hard disk, and reallocate new drives. The boot memory is re-allocated during drives partition.

Hope it helps you :)